# Secure modulus length for Diffie-Hellman

Tags: diffie-hellman

What is secure modulus length for modular exponentiation so that finding discrete log is computationaly impossible?

Comment: See [this](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/how-large-should-a-diffie-hellman-p-be-if-the-messages-are-encrypted). I think your question is a duplicate or at least answered by the other.

Comment: _<if the messages are encrypted.>_ - no, not really

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3526, Security considerations.

Comment: _May 2003_ . You are a bad CO.

Comment: Well, RFC 3526 is still valid and it is consistent with the recommendations of e.g. NIST SP 800-56A, which was published in 2007 and is also still valid. I presume these estimates won't change much until there is some major break through in either DL algorithms or quantum computing.

Comment: Yes, but computing capabilities have grown a litte since then.

Comment: The increase in computing capabilities means you probably shouldn't use keys with an estimated 80 bit security strength. Just move up the table to e.g. 2048 bit prime modulus with a 256 bit group order, which still corresponds to roughly 128 bit security.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, read the answer closer.